# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^{2x}{xe^{x^2}}dx}{e^{4x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, derivatives

> I have the following limit:
>
> $$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\int_{0}^{2x}{xe^{x^2}dx}}{e^{4x^2}}$$

How do I evaluate the numerator? This is what I've tried doing:

$$\int_{0}^{2x}{xe^{x^2}dx}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2x}{e^{x^2}(2x.dx)}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2x}{e^{x^2}.d(x^2)}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2} \left[e^{x^2}\right]_{0}^{2x}$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{2} \left(e^{4x^2}-1\right)$$

Is this correct?

Also, is there a general way of evaluating the following (where $f(t)$ is just any real valued function and $n \in \mathbb Z$)?

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x^n} {f(t).dt}$$

Do we have to do somehow evaluate the integral, apply the limits and only then take the derivative, or is there a different way of doing it?

---

(These are not 2 different questions, I'm asking about the derivative because I'm trying to use L'Hôpital's rule to find the limit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your integral is correct. Then$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\int_0^{2x}te^{t^2}dt}{e^{4x^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{4x^2}-1}{e^{4x^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{e^{4x^2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

For your last question, in general $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^n}f(t)dt=nx^{n-1}
f(x^n)$$

by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question: can we also generalize the following-
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^m}^{x^n}f(t)dt$$ where $m<n$?

Comment: Thanks again, that makes a lot more sense. Also, if you don't mind me asking, where can I find a proof for the fundamental theorem of calculus? I've read about the theorem itself in a textbook, but there was no proof given.

Comment: Thanks again! Yes I'll keep in mind that this is not a very rigorous proof, but considering the fact that I'm just out of high school, I don't think I should worry about that (yet).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is using l'Hopital, then
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\int_{0}^{2x}{te^{t^2}dt}}{e^{4x^2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{2\times 2xe^{4x^2}}{8xe^{4x^2}} = \dfrac12$$